# How to make a dashed line with scissors in ConTeXt?

Tags: fonts, symbols, context, line

I ran out of ways to introduce a simple horizontal dashed line with scissors at its beginning to indicate the cut line of the paper. I am a bit new to ConTeXt wonderful land. I came across this page in the ConTeXt [wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Symbols) but couldn't make it. However, I found the symbols that I am after in the `martinvogel 2` collection as shown [here](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Symbols/mvs), namely the `Cutright`, `Kutline`. There I am seeing a warning that some symbols are outdated by now, I hope I can still have the cutline with the scissors though. Tomorrow is my deadline to submit the document. I did 99% of it and this is the last remaining detail to do.

I could show the zodiac set by putting `\showsymbolset[zodiac]` in the preamble, but `\showsymbolset[mvs]` did not show anything.

Your help would be very much appreciated.

**MWE**

```
\setuppapersize [A4]

\usesymbols[mvs]
%\showsymbolset[zodiac]
%\showsymbolset[mvs]

\setupsymbolset[martinvogel 2]

\starttext

{\sc SOME TEXT.}
\blank[big]

\blackrule[width=\hsize,height=2pt]

\symbol[Kutline]                %Cutline, Cutright, 

{\sc SOME TEXT.}
\blank[big]
{\sc Secret No.}



\stoptext


%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: context
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% TeX-engine: luatex
%%% End:
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the filler mechanism (a wrapper for `\leaders` command in TeX) which repeats a symbol until the end of the line is reached.

```
\usesymbols[mvs]

\definefiller
  [Cutline]
  [  left={\symbol[martinvogel 2][CutLeft]},
    right={\symbol[martinvogel 2][CutRight]},
   symbol={\symbol[martinvogel 2][CutLine]},
   method=broad,
    width=0pt]

\starttext

\input jojomayer

\filler[Cutline]

\stoptext
```

[image: Scissors line to cut the paper]

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to the `\filler` mechanism, day saved!

Comment: can I control the thickness of the filler? by font size or is there another trick? I used `{\switchtobodyfont [25pt]
\filler[Cutline]}`.

Comment: @doctorate The thickness of the dashed line and the size of the scissors depend on the font size and `\switchtobodyfont` is one way to change it.